# Pygame is lagging in WSL, but not in windows

Tags: python, windows, ubuntu, pygame, windows-subsystem-for-linux

```
import sys 

import pygame

from settings import Settings
from ship import Ship


class AlienInvasion:
    """Overall class to manage game assets and behaviour."""

    def __init__(self):
        """Initializethe game, and create game resources"""
        pygame.init()
        self.settings = Settings()

        self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode((0, 0), pygame.FULLSCREEN)
        self.settings.screen_height = self.screen.get_rect().height
        self.settings.screen_width = self.screen.get_rect().width
        pygame.display.set_caption("Alien Invasion")

        self.ship = Ship(self)


    def run_game(self):
        """Start the main loop for the game."""
        while True:
            self._check_events()
            self.ship.update()
            self._update_screen()

            

    
    def _check_events(self):
        """responds to keypresses and mouse events."""
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                sys.exit()
            
            elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                self._check_keydown_events(event)

            elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
                self._check_keyup_events(event)

    def _check_keydown_events(self, event):
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                self.ship.moving_right = True
            elif event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                self.ship.moving_left = True
            elif event.key == pygame.K_q:
                sys.exit()  

    def _check_keyup_events(self, event):
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                self.ship.moving_right = False
            elif event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                self.ship.moving_left = False    
    
    def _update_screen(self):
        """Update images on the screen, and flip to the new screen."""
        self.screen.fill(self.settings.bg_color)
        self.ship.blitme()

        pygame.display.flip()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Make a game instance, and run the game.
    ai = AlienInvasion()
    ai.run_game()
```

I am trying to learn to use pygame to create games, I am currently working on the Alien Invasion.
I am using windows subsystem for Linux in Ubuntu flavor, but the frame rate is really low, it's unplayable.
Also, I think GWSL does not go more than 60Hz even though my display support 144Hz.

I tried Clock function to make the game smoother by setting the FPS manually but it made the motions very fast that it was also unplayable.
I tried running the game on windows and it was much smoother.

Comment: my solution should work, see my answer.

Comment: @DeanVanGreunen No your solution doesn't work.

Comment: This is not a problem with the code, but with the system.

Comment: `WSL` has to run more code to simulate Linux - so other programs may work slower. Why to use `WSL`, run only in Windows. Display's speed (144Mhz) has nothing to do with game speed. If game works slow then faster display can't change it. I would use `clock.tick(30)` to have the same speed for fast and slow computers (for new and old computers). But if computer/system is very slow then it will not help. If you want smoother game on faster computer (and still keep less frames on slower computer) then you may need to use `delta time` instead of `tick`